# Finding the optimal HSV parameters for colour identification through Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a `CSV` file like below:

[image: GroundTruth dataset]

Is it possible to find the optimal lower and upper HSV bound through machine learning for the following function?

[image]

The function which I use is:

[image]

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.